# Wafer thickness reduction (750 µm to 50 µm)

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors

Need some suggestions as to what techniques one could possibly adopt to reduce wafer thickness to 50 µm or less while fulfilling these 2 conditions :

- Surface roughmess, Ra < 3nm
- Total Thickness Variation < 3µm

Comment: very fine sandpaper?

Comment: You need a chemical mechanical wafer polishing machine .... try Applied Materials (if they are still in business) or second hand... oh and some horrible chemicals they are too... good luck with the chip hacking.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to buy the right equipment ?
http://eesemi.com/backgrind.htm
http://www.syagrussystems.com/wafer-backgrinding